# Sync Diigo with Google Bookmarks

Tags: google-bookmarks, diigo

How can I sync Diigo with Google Bookmarks without having to manually import/export continuously?

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

At this time it's not possible from the Diigo Web UI.

## Alternatives

Use the Diigo API or third party tool.

## References

- [Import Bookmarks - Diigo Help](https://www.diigo.com/tools/import_all)
- [Diigo API](https://www.diigo.com/api_dev)

Comment: Which third party tool? I know IFTT, but maybe there are other ones?