# Sync Diigo with Chrome Browser Bookmarks

Tags: synchronization, diigo, chrome-bookmarks

How can I **sync Diigo** with my **Chrome browser bookmarks** without having to manually import/export continuously?

<sub>**Before you mark it as a duplicate again, please read the question carefully** and realize that it is a distinct and different question than [my question about syncing Diigo with Google Bookmarks](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9022/sync-diigo-with-google-bookmarks).  Google Bookmarks and Chrome browser bookmarks are not the same thing.  If this is in fact a duplicate of some other post can you let me know before closing it because I can't find any other post that covers this question.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can.

You can have an RSS feed that could be accessed in Chrome using an extension. Or you could cobble something together yourself - perhaps by using the RSS feed into a blog (WordPress maybe) and then having some scripts to do the final sync - however, I'm not convinced it would work. Chrome is very tight on security and I doubt it would let you easily script the uploading of bookmarks. Perhaps something like AutoHotKey would let you do it.